Configuring SSL/TLS encryption for data in transit - GridDB
I’m trying to configure secure data storage and retrieval using the GridDB database with TLS/SSL encryption for data in transit. I want to encrypt sensitive data before storing it and decrypt it upon retrieval. I'm using the cryptography library to handle encryption. Here is my code:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import griddb_python as griddb

# Generating an encryption key and encrypting data
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
data = "Sensitive Data"
encrypted_data = cipher_suite.encrypt(data.encode())

# Setting up GridDB connection
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
try:
    gridstore = factory.get_store(
        host="localhost", port=10001, cluster_name="defaultCluster",
        username="admin", password="admin"
    )

    # Create or get container
    container_name = "data_encryption_test"
    conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo(
        name=container_name,
        column_info_list=[["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                          ["data", griddb.Type.STRING]],
        type=griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, row_key=True)
    
    container = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)
    container.set_auto_commit(False)
    
    # Storing encrypted data
    row = [1, encrypted_data.decode()]
    container.put_row(row)
    container.commit()

    # Retrieving and decrypting data
    query = container.query("select *")
    rs = query.fetch()
    while rs.has_next():
        row = rs.next()
        encrypted_data_retrieved = row[1].encode()
        decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(encrypted_data_retrieved).decode()
        print("Decrypted Data:", decrypted_data)

except griddb.GSException as e:
    print("GridDB Error:", e)

Issue: When running the code, I encounter an error during data decryption after retrieving the data from GridDB:
TypeError: token must be bytes

What I’ve Tried:

Double-checked the conversion between strings and bytes.

Confirmed the GridDB connection is working for basic queries without encryption.


Expected Behavior: The code should store encrypted data in the GridDB container and retrieve and decrypt it successfully.
